# Assign text formats per user roles

Tags: hooks, users

I tried to program the logic where friends_html text format would apply to nodes saved by users with the new 'friends' role, while friends_somik_my_html text format would apply to nodes saved by all 'other' users.

```
function somik_core_node_presave($node) {
  if (!empty($node->nid)) {
    // if it was unpublished update the created/changed
    if ($node->original->status==0 && $node->status==1) {
      $node->created = time();
      $node->changed = time();
    }
  }

  module_load_include('inc', 'somik_core', 'somik_core.base64_images');
  somik_core_remove_node_base64_images($node);

  // apply saved html filter
  $somik_my_html_format = filter_format_load('somik_my_html');
  $field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'body');
  if ($somik_my_html_format && !empty($field[0]['value'])) {
    $body_value = check_markup($field[0]['value'], 'somik_my_html');
    $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $body_value;
    $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['safe_value'] = $body_value;
  }

  if ($node->format == 'friends_somik_my_html') {
    if (array_key_exists('others', $user->roles)) {
      // apply others saved html filter
      $friends_somik_my_html_format = filter_format_load('friends_somik_my_html');
      $field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'body');
      if ($somik_my_html_format && !empty($field[0]['value'])) {
        $body_value = check_markup($field[0]['value'], 'friends_somik_my_html');
        $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $body_value;
        $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['safe_value'] = $body_value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind filters is that you store the raw input in the database, and sanitise it *on display*.

So really all you need to do is update the format for the body field, like so:

```
// Apply somik_my_html filter
$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format'] = 'somik_my_html';
```

Comment: I was pretty sure I was able to use "Full HTML" input format, and anonymous users was seeing nodes just the way I did, without permission to actually use any formats at all. And redactors without "Full HTML" format access was simply unable to edit that node, but seen it the way I did, too. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yep you're totally right, I got confused with permissions on editing :)

Comment: OK, now I can agree with your answer. Only thing I don't know is why not to simply limit user roles to given format types using built-in permission system - and add put needed filters in corresponding formats, of course. It seems it can be done without a single line of code.

Comment: Hmmm that's a very good point, I didn't even think of that. I reckon the OP just hasn't got to grips with the whole 'store the original, sanitise on display' paradigm yet, and is trying to work out how to get around it. It's probably the same thing I would have done a few years ago before I got a rollocking from one of the core devs for sanitising _before_ saving to the database!

Comment: hello @clive i updated the code, will you please check and figure out what is the problem??

Comment: @Somik No I'm not going to do that. You've completely ignored the answer that I've given, you haven't even acknowledged it, and the code update you've made makes it obvious you haven't taken this advice on board. I don't think you understand the point of this site; we're here to answer specific, objective questions. We're not here to support _anyone_ through the development of a specific feature for their site. It sounds like you need to hire a Drupal contractor to help you out, or perhaps organise some Drupal training

Comment: actually am in big problem clive i tried with your line also but not worked in my case, anyway thanks

Comment: @Somik Apologies if my tone sounded off there, not my intention. The problem is, it's _very_ difficult to understand what your problem is. You haven't given enough background/context to the question for us to understand what you're trying to achieve, and what's going wrong. I think this is just because of the language barrier; if you know anyone who can help with your English to get this question a bit more comprehensible, that would be great, and would probably get you an answer much quicker :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply limit user roles to given format types using built-in permission system - and add put needed filters in corresponding formats, of course. It seems it can be done without a single line of code.

And if you need changes during presentation, use theme system. Just remember that it can lead to problems - if moderator sees content in different way than some users, or if author sees it different than his audience, it's an easy way for inconsistencies and artefacts.